# Ошибка реализации Toast

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В чем может быть проблема ? Хочу выводить уведомление, когда происходит нажатие. Использую `Toast`, нажатие будет происходить в списке `RecyclerView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код следует добавлять в вопрос текстом, а не скрином

Comment: извиняюсь, в следующий раз буду исправляться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Toast.makeText` первым аргументом принимает `Context`, в рамках которого будет показан тостер.

Используйте вместо `ProductAdapter.this` - `context` (определенный вами ранее в конструкторе).